# How to add leading zero in time?

Tags: javascript, time

Here first I am converting `11:00` to minutes in function `convertH2M` and then Lessing `12 hours means` `720 minute` from `660 minutes (11:00 hrs.)` and I am getting minutes in negative and I am converting it in hours
in function `convertM2H` now I want convert that negative(`-1:0`) time like this `01:00` is it possible to do that? if yes, than how ?

***NOTE :***   that if the time is `13:00` than I value comes in positive Time can be anything instead of `11:00` it could be any `from 00:00 to 23:00`

```
function convertH2M(timeInHour) {
  var timeParts = timeInHour.split(":");
  return Number(timeParts[0]) * 60 + Number(timeParts[1]);
}

var timeInMinutes = convertH2M(11:00);

function convertM2H(t) {
  var hours = (t / 60);
  var rhours = Math.floor(hours);
  var minutes = (hours - rhours) * 60;
  var rminutes = Math.round(minutes);
  return rhours + ":" + rminutes

}
let callback_time_InMinutes = timeInMinutes - 720
                if (callback_time_InMinutes < 15) {
                    return res.status(403).send(error.TIMEMISSMATCH);
                }
let call_back = convertM2H(callback_time_InMinutes)
req.body.call_back = call_back
```

Comment: Quick-and-dirty: `'0' + hours.toString()`. But the best solution is to use `Moment.js`.

Comment: Also look at the `Intl` library in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl

Comment: But yes - date-formatting (and formatting in-general) in JavaScript is a huge pain. Welcome to JavaScript :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the hours and the minutes to string in `convertM2H` and use [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) function since you already returning a string

```
function convertM2H(t) {
  var hours = Number.parseInt(t / 60);
  var minutes = t % 60; // assuming t is the time in minutes

  return `${String(hours).padStart(2,"0")}:${String(rminutes).padStart(2,"0")}`
}
```

Comment: gladly. I cleaned a bit your hours and minutes calculation too

Answer (score 0):

I am able to convert negative value in positive with below `convert_positive` function

```
const convert_positive= (t) => {
  // Check the number is negative 
  if (t < 0) {
      // Multiply number with -1 
      // to make it positive 
      t = t * -1;
  }
  // Return the positive number 
  return t;
}

function convertH2M(timeInHour) {
  var timeParts = timeInHour.split(":");
  return Number(timeParts[0]) * 60 + Number(timeParts[1]);
}

var timeInMinutes = convertH2M(11:00);

function convertM2H(t) {
  var hours = (t / 60);
  var rhours = Math.floor(hours);
  var minutes = (hours - rhours) * 60;
  var rminutes = Math.round(minutes);
  return rhours + ":" + rminutes

}
let callback_time_InMinutes = timeInMinutes - 720
                if (callback_time_InMinutes < 15) {
                    return res.status(403).send(error.TIMEMISSMATCH);
                }
let callback_time_Inpositive = convert_positive(callback_time_InMinutes);
let call_back = convertM2H(callback_time_Inpositive );
req.body.call_back = call_back
```